# Why is my Post List component not loading?

Tags: javascript, angular, routes, angular-router

so as the question states, I have a component inside my post module, namely, PostList. What it is supposed to do is to load as soon as the user accesses the website.
The code for it is as follows
**posts-list.component.css**

```css
section {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(auto-fit, minmax(300px,1fr));
  grid-template-rows: auto;
  grid-gap: 10px;
  margin: 0 auto;
  max-width: 90%;
}
mat-card {
  margin: 10px 0;
}
```

**post-list.component.html**

```html
<section>
  <mat-card *ngFor="let post of posts | async">
    <mat-card-content routerLink="{{post.id}}">
      <img mat-card-image src="{{post.image}}" alt="{{post.title}}">
      <h2>{{post.title}}</h2>
      <p>
        <small>Posted by {{post.author}} &bull; on {{post.published | date:"fullDate"}}</small>
      </p>
    </mat-card-content>
    <mat-card-actions align="end" *ngIf="auth.currentUserId === post.authorId">
      <button mat-icon-button (click)="delete(post.id)">
        <mat-icon>delete</mat-icon>
      </button>
    </mat-card-actions>
  </mat-card>
</section>
```

**post-list.component.ts**

```js
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core'
import { Observable } from 'rxjs/Observable'

import { PostService } from '../posts.service'
import { Post } from '../post'
import { AuthService } from '../../core/auth.service'

@Component({
  selector: 'app-post-list',
  templateUrl: './post-list.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./post-list.component.css']
})
export class PostListComponent implements OnInit {
  posts: Observable<Post[]>
  constructor(private postService: PostService, public auth: AuthService) {}

  ngOnInit() {
    this.posts = this.postService.getPosts()
  }

  delete(id: string) {
    this.postService.delete(id)
  }

}
```

Since it is inside a module, I have routed it to open as **/blog** in the **post.module.ts**

```js
const routes: Routes = [
{path:'blog',component:PostListComponent},
{path:'blog/:id',component:PostDetailComponent},
{path:'dashboard',component:PostDashboardComponent}
]
```

I cannot figure out why it isn't displaying on the website.

In the app.module.ts

```
const routes: Routes = [
  { path: '', redirectTo: '/blog', pathMatch: 'full'},
  { path: '', loadChildren: './posts/posts.module#PostsModule' },

]
```

posts.service.ts

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core'
import {
  AngularFirestore,
  AngularFirestoreCollection,
  AngularFirestoreDocument
} from '@angular/fire/firestore'
import { Post } from './post'
import 'rxjs/add/operator/map'


@Injectable()
export class PostService {
  postsCollection: AngularFirestoreCollection<Post>
  postDoc: AngularFirestoreDocument<Post>

  constructor(private afs: AngularFirestore) {
    this.postsCollection = this.afs.collection('posts', ref =>
      ref.orderBy('published', 'desc')
    )
  }

  getPosts() {
    return this.postsCollection.snapshotChanges().map(actions => {
      return actions.map(a => {
        const data = a.payload.doc.data() as Post
        const id = a.payload.doc.id
        return { id, ...data }
      })
    })
  }

  getPostData(id: string) {
    this.postDoc = this.afs.doc<Post>(`posts/${id}`)
    return this.postDoc.valueChanges()
  }

  getPost(id: string) {
    return this.afs.doc<Post>(`posts/${id}`)
  }

  create(data: Post) {
    this.postsCollection.add(data)
  }

  delete(id: string) {
    return this.getPost(id).delete()
  }

  update(id: string, formData) {
    return this.getPost(id).update(formData)
  }
}
```

Please guide me on what I am doing wrong. I just cannot figure it out.

Comment: try to change the order of your paths, making blog/:id before blog

Comment: please subscribe to ```this.postService.getPosts()``` post service getPosts() method

Comment: Your routing is wrong, see https://angular.io/guide/lazy-loading-ngmodules#imports-and-route-configuration

Comment: what is the `size` of `posts`.?

Comment: Please post the code of `PostService`

Comment: Any error in console?

Comment: @VivekDoshi I have done it. I am extremely sorry for editing it this late.

Comment: @hrdkisback no errors at all

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you need to load your module differently
in the **app.module.ts**

```
const routes: Routes = [{
  path: 'blog',
  loadChildren: () => import('./modules/posts/posts.module').then(m => m.PostsModule),
},
{ 
  path: '',
  redirectTo: '/blog',
  pathMatch: 'full'
},
{
  path:'dashboard',
  component:PostDashboardComponent
}]
```

Note: in Angular 8 and above, we use a different way of loading modules, the one you used: `./posts/posts.module#PostsModule` is the old way, see [Angular docs](https://angular.io/guide/router#lazy-loading-route-configuration).

And change your **post.module.ts** routes to

```
const routes: Routes = [
  {path:'',component:PostListComponent},
  {path:':id',component:PostDetailComponent}
]
```

Comment: Since post dashboard component is inside the post module, it cannot be routed directly in the app.module.ts :(

Comment: Then, add that component to the post.module.ts instead, and add ‘dashboard’ as a separate path (makig it blog/dashboard) in the url. Remember to add it before the path with :id

Answer (score -1):

Try like this

```
ngOnInit() {
    this.postService.getPosts().subscribe((response: any)=> {
      this.posts = response;
   })
  }
```

Answer (score -1):

```
this.postService.getPosts().subscribe((posts) => this.posts = posts);
```

Observables are lazy. Please subscribe to start them.

Answer (score -1):

```
    Change the 
 { path: '', redirectTo: '/blog', pathMatch: 'full'},
      { path: '', loadChildren: './posts/posts.module#PostsModule' }
    to 
      { path: 'blog', loadChildren: './posts/posts.module#PostsModule' }

    You can remove the { path: '', redirectTo: '/blog', pathMatch: 'full'} .
    Assuming the './posts' path is correct.
    When the route matches with /blog it checks in the postmodule routing 
     ,it checks with 
    const routes: Routes = [
    {path:'blog',component:PostListComponent},
    {path:'blog/:id',component:PostDetailComponent},
    {path:'dashboard',component:PostDashboardComponent}
    ]
    and serves the PostListComponent
```

Comment: Your answer was the most helpful, but unfortunately, it still does not work.

Comment: Firstly, is the page being displayed , I mean is it navigated to the desired page